# How to call a Python Bottle API from within that application

Tags: python, bottle

I have created an API using the Bottle Library in Python. It endpoints look like this

```
@app.get('/api/users/<id>', name='user')
def get_user(model, id):

    user = model.get_user(id)
    if not user:
        return HTTPError(404, 'User not found')
    else:
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        return json.dumps(user)
```

I want to call the API in other functions within the same app

```
@app.route('/users/<id>')
def users (id=1):
    user = request.get("http://localhost:8001/api/user/1")
    return template('user', user=user)
```

However, this is showing no results. The request get timed out each time

So my question is, how to call a bottle API from within that app using Requests library or through any other means.

Comment: This looks a bad design where you have two different endpoints doing same work for a same resource i.e Users. If at all you want to call another endpoint, use Redirect to client with the new URI.

But still, this is not the right approach and I don't understand your use case of having same endpoint with just namespace difference(/api)

Comment: @Saurabh. The /api namespace will return json object. The /user namespace will return an html page that displays that object with formating.

Comment: Well then I would recommend creating a service layer to handle your request, which will create your User object, do some validations etc. and have a specific response based on mime type, instead of calling an endpoint - this will not work.

Comment: If you want to use your JSON API to render your web page, one approach would be write JS script which calls that API and populates page according. But I agree with @Saurabh. Your approach here isn't going to work. Create separate method to search users and user it in both API and Web endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Bottle in single-threaded mode (the default)? If so, then your internal `get` request will hang forever. This is because your server can serve only one request at a time, and you are asking it to handle two at once: the first call to `/users/<id>`, and then the second call to `/api/users/<id>`.

A band-aid fix would be to [run the server in asynchronous mode](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html). Try this method and see if your timeouts go away:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=YOUR_PORT_NUMBER, server='gevent')
```

**However**: You shouldn't be designing your application this way in the first place. Instead, refactor your code so that both methods can call a function that returns the JSON representation of a user. Then one api call can return that raw json object, while the other api call can present it as HTML. NOTE: that's not how I would design this API, but it's the answer that's the shortest distance from how you've structured your application so far.